# Python Random Number File Writer

Tags: python, function

This is what I have so far. It worked until I added the functions. I need to have two functions in the code and I don't know how to make this work correctly and have tried several different ways. The code needs to write X amount of random numbers to a text file.

```
import random

random_numbers = open('ran_numbers.txt', 'w')

def main():

    getRandom()
    writeFunction()

def getRandom():
    qty_numbers = int(input('How many random numbers should be written to the file? '))

    for count in range (qty_numbers):
        number = random.randint(1,500)

def writeFunction():
    random_numbers.write(str(number)+ '\n')
    random_numbers.close()
    print('Your list of random numbers have been written to the file named')
    print('ran_numbers.txt')

main()
```

Comment: `getRandom` doesn’t `return` anything, so as far as the rest of the program is concerned, that function is not doing anything. Then, `writeFunction` tries to use something called `number` but there’s no such variable in your program. There are a couple of other problems too, but first, try this: write a simpler program that just asks you how many numbers you want and then *prints* out that many random numbers. With that down, you can move on to writing them to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
random_numbers = open('ran_numbers.txt', 'w')

def main():

    getRandom()
    writeFunction()

def getRandom():
    qty_numbers = int(input('How many random numbers should be written to the file? '))

    for count in range (qty_numbers):
        number = random.randint(1,500)
```

To this:

```
random_numbers = open('ran_numbers.txt', 'w')

def main():

    getRandom()


def getRandom():
    qty_numbers = int(input('How many random numbers should be written to the file? '))

    for count in range (qty_numbers):
        number = random.randint(1,500)
        writeFunction(number)
```

Because, numbers is a local variable for the getRandom() function, so either directly write to the file in that function itself or return the number in the main function and pass it to writeFunction()

```
def main():
    number= getRandom()
    writeFunction(number)
```

What you do is your choice, but defining number in one block isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You never call the writeFunction() after creating the random number

Just change:

```
for count in range (qty_numbers):
    number = random.randint(1,500)
```

to this:

```
for count in range (qty_numbers):
    number = random.randint(1,500)
    writeFunction(number)
```

and change the line:

```
def writeFunction():
```

to:

```
def writeFunction(number):
```

and finally change your main() to:

```
def main():

    getRandom()
    random_numbers.close()
```

and remove

```
random_numbers.close()
```

from the writeFunction()

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Can you also explain where `random_numbers.close()` ought to go?

Comment: I would put it at the end of the main() function, that way the file is only closed once after the function is completed.

Comment: Right, I meant, can you amend your answer to contain that info 

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to have a list of numbers that are generatred and pass them to the file_writer. Here is the change I made to your code:

```
import random
def main():
    random_result = getRandom()
    writeFunction(random_result)
def getRandom():
    qty_numbers = int(input('How many random numbers should be written to the file? '))
    res = []
    for count in range (qty_numbers):
        res.append(random.randint(1,500))
    return res 
def writeFunction(random_numbers_list):
    random_numbers = open('ran_numbers.txt', 'w')
    for number in random_numbers_list:
        random_numbers.write(str(number)+ '\n')
    random_numbers.close()
    print('Your list of random numbers have been written to the file named')
    print('ran_numbers.txt')
main()
```

Comment: This won’t run because `getRandom` is used before it’s defined. I think you accidentally left some superfluous code at the beginning of `main`. Can you edit to fix this?

Comment: I mistakenly indented the definition of the function, Just fixed it. Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you MUST have two functions then this would be a better solution. Putting the random numbers in a list and then passing it onto the writeFunction function.

```
import random

random_numbers = open('ran_numbers.txt', 'w')

def main():

    writeFunction(getRandom())

def getRandom():
    qty_numbers = int(input('How many random numbers should be written to     the file? '))

    nums = []
    for count in range (qty_numbers):
        nums.append(random.randint(1,500))
    return nums

def writeFunction(a_list):
    random_nums = '\n'.join([str(x) for x in a_list])
    random_numbers.write(random_nums)
    random_numbers.close()
    print('Your list of random numbers have been written to the file named')
    print('ran_numbers.txt')

main()
```